# How to identify the decoding result is error?

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Let $(15,11,3)_2$ be a linear code and the parity check matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\0&1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\\end{pmatrix}.$$

Suppose the sent codeword is $(000111100001111)$, and the error is $(111000000000000)$(the weight is 3).
Then the received codeword is $(111111100001111)$. It is easy to check that the syndrome decoding using the nearest codeword principle will identity it as a codeword, which is clearly wrong.
How to handle this case?
I know if the weight of error $t \leq (d-1)/2$, the decoder can run correctly.

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot handle this at all without an extra layer somewhere. Say, if the information in this block is a part of longer stream of data, protected by a CRC or some such, then you can tell that something went wrong. But still you would not know what. The point of error-correction is to reduce the probability of an incorrect interpretation. It cannot make that probability exactly zero. When designing a system you first agree on a certain Quality Of Service, and then find FEC parameters that deliver what is wanted.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain more "When designing a system you first agree on a certain Quality Of Service, and then find FEC parameters that deliver what is wanted."? I dont know what is "Quality Of Service" and "FEC".

Comment: [FEC = (Forward Error Correction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code#Forward_error_correction). I equate it with the use of an error-correcting code, but FEC is the term telcomm engineers use. I guess there is room for differences (or other methods of error control). QoS is another acronym the engineers like. To give an example I am somewhat familiar with. When designing the digital video broadcast standard currently in use in Europe, it was first decided that consumers can tolerate a bit error probability of $10^{-11}$ (or was it $10^{-12}$?).

Comment: Considering that a typical HDTV stream runs at 10 megabits per second of compressed video, BER level $10^{-11}$ translates to one bit error in $10 000$ seconds. Or (as mpeg doesn't degrade very gracefully) one flicker of the screen (likely only affecting a small region) every 3 hours. In other words, something that somebody else decides, and the designers of the error-correcting-code need to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful interpretation!

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered to some satisfaction in the comment by [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen), as written by the poster in another comment.

From the comments:

1. "The short answer is that you cannot handle this at all without an extra layer somewhere. Say, if the information in this block is a part of longer stream of data, protected by a CRC or some such, then you can tell that something went wrong. But still you would not know what. The point of error-correction is to reduce the probability of an incorrect interpretation. It cannot make that probability exactly zero. When designing a system you first agree on a certain Quality Of Service, and then find FEC parameters that deliver what is wanted."
2. "[FEC = (Forward Error Correction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code#Forward_error_correction). I equate it with the use of an error-correcting code, but FEC is the term telcomm engineers use. I guess there is room for differences (or other methods of error control). QoS is another acronym the engineers like. To give an example I am somewhat familiar with. When designing the digital video broadcast standard currently in use in Europe, it was first decided that consumers can tolerate a bit error probability of $10^{-11}$ (or was it $10^{-12}$?)."
3. "Considering that a typical HDTV stream runs at 10 megabits per second of compressed video, BER level $10^{-11}$ translates to one bit error in $10000$ seconds. Or (as mpeg doesn't degrade very gracefully) one flicker of the screen (likely only affecting a small region) every 3 hours. In other words, something that somebody else decides, and the designers of the error-correcting-code need to achieve."